# PCBA Upgrade help - best route for processor upgrade

Tags: serial, microprocessor

I have a PCBA currently which:

- Runs a Linux Kernel
- Communicates through 4 RS232 serial poets
- Communicates through Ethernet port

It currently uses an AM335x processor, which I am finding is not quite powerful enough to process the serial comms.

So what would be the easiest upgrade path, the best processor I can use? Preferably with on chip memory?

Comment: rewrite the software first ... serial comm is not that processor intensive

Comment: A Linux kernel can be, though.